# How to avoid creation of Duplicate events in calendar in android

Tags: android

I have added events in my own calendar in application by creating account but when ever i synchronize via Sync Calendar through Sync & Account Manager, event get duplicated So How can i check whether event already exist or not . i have optimized following code but it seems not working properly.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();

            Date dt = null;
            Date dt1 = null;

            try {
                dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(Stime);
                dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(Etime);

                cal.setTime(dt);
                // beginTime.set(2013, 7, 25, 7, 30);
                beginTime.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        cal.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                        cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                cal.setTime(dt1);
                // endTime.set(2013, 7, 25, 14, 30);
                endTime.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        cal.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                        cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            String selection = "((" + Instances.DTSTART + " = '"
                    + beginTime.getTimeInMillis() + "') AND ("
                    + Instances.DTEND + " = '" + endTime.getTimeInMillis()
                    + "') AND (" + Instances.TITLE + " = '" + EventName
                    + "') AND (" + Instances.CALENDAR_ID + " = '"
                    + cal_event_id + "'))";

            Log.i("EVENT NAME", "   " + EventName);
            Log.i("EVENT STIME", "  " + Stime);
            Log.i("EVENT ETIME", "  " + Etime);

            Uri.Builder builder = Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, endTime.getTimeInMillis());

            long begin = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();// starting time in
                                                        // milliseconds
            long end = endTime.getTimeInMillis(); // ending time in milliseconds
            String[] proj = new String[] { Instances._ID, Instances.DTSTART,
                    Instances.DTEND, Instances.EVENT_ID, Instances.TITLE,
                    Instances.CALENDAR_ID };

            Cursor cursor = Instances.query(this.mContext.getContentResolver(),
                    proj, begin, end);

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                // deal with conflict
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    long id = 0;
                    id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));
                    long eventid = 0;
                    eventid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("EVENT_ID"));

                    String event_Name = null;
                    event_Name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("TITLE"));
                    Log.i("event_Name", event_Name);

                    long Calid = 0;
                    Calid = cursor
                            .getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("CALENDAR_ID"));

                    if (event_Name.equalsIgnoreCase(EventName)) {
                        String[] j = cursor.getColumnNames();
                        Log.i("DUPLICATE", "-------- " + EventName + "ID:::"
                                + id + "==" + j[1] + "==" + j[2] + "EVENTID::"
                                + eventid + "==" + j[4] + "CALENDARID::"
                                + Calid);
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        Log.i("LATEST", "CAST");
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("LATEST", "-------- " + cursor.getCount());
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: r u using device calender?

Comment: First i have created Own Calendar which id is 1 and over new calendar i have added events...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How i have implemented an alternative way to checking whether event already registered or not in calendar...

```
public boolean isEventInCal(Context context, String cal_meeting_id) {

 Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
 Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
   new String[] { "_id" }, " _id = ? ",
   new String[] { cal_meeting_id }, null);

       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi in this answer what is cal_meeting_id

Comment: @Ram That's event id.

Comment: ya i found that

Answer (score 1):

A simple thing I did (for an alarm) was query if an event with the same properties already existed, and adding it only if it didn't.
This gives you also the possibility to update existing entries.

Comment: I have been Facing Problem with Time Zone...actually event Added one day before the date and i m running with 24hr timezone +5.30 gmt..

Comment: I am also facing same problem event Added one day before the date  how to solve this issue. @DhruvitDarji