# How Do I Programmatically Add Reminders To A Calendar Event Using Events URI?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to figure out how to add reminders to a Calendar Event in my android app. The image below circled in red is what I want to programmatically add to my code below the image. That's what I'm having a hard time with. I'll appreciate the help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luCSa.jpg)

This is what I have so far... Everything works fine except for what I need help with.

```
 public void addEventToCalendar(String EventTitle, String EventDescription, String EventLocation, int EventStartDateYear, int EventStartDateMonth, int EventStartDateDay, int EventEndDateYear, int EventEndDateMonth, int EventEndDateDay, int BeginHour, int BeginMin, int EndHour, int EndMin, Boolean AllDay, String EventFrequency) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Event To Your Calendar...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        Calendar startcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar endcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startcalendar.set(EventStartDateYear, EventStartDateMonth, EventStartDateDay, BeginHour, BeginMin);
        endcalendar.set(EventStartDateYear, EventEndDateMonth, EventEndDateDay, EndHour, EndMin);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, EventTitle);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, EventDescription);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, EventLocation);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startcalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endcalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, AllDay);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 5); //this here is what I am trying to figure out... 5 minutes before event or 5 hours before event, or 5 days before event, etc.
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, EventFrequency);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "GMT-05:00");
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
        eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    } else {
        eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }
    Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Event Added To Your Calendar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert an entry into CalendarContract.Reminders, e.g.

```
public void addEventToCalendar(String EventTitle, String EventDescription, String EventLocation, int EventStartDateYear, int EventStartDateMonth, int EventStartDateDay, int EventEndDateYear, int EventEndDateMonth, int EventEndDateDay, int BeginHour, int BeginMin, int EndHour, int EndMin, Boolean AllDay, String EventFrequency) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Event To Your Calendar...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    Calendar startcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startcalendar.set(EventStartDateYear, EventStartDateMonth, EventStartDateDay, BeginHour, BeginMin);
    endcalendar.set(EventStartDateYear, EventEndDateMonth, EventEndDateDay, EndHour, EndMin);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, EventTitle);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, EventDescription);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, EventLocation);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startcalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endcalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, AllDay);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, EventFrequency);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "GMT-05:00");

    Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, event);

    long eventId = Long.parseLong(url.getLastPathSegment());

    ContentValues reminder = new ContentValues();
    reminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventId);
    reminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 10);
    reminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
    getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminder);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Event Added To Your Calendar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately,

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'method' is invalid at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165) at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135) at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476) at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1545)

Comment: I updated the answer to show what works for me - note you need to insert into a Calendar that allows notifications, for the default calendar you need to be signed in for this to work.

Also, for devices running on Android M you will need to request permission in addition to the uses-permission flags declared in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Can you also add a runtime permissions for calendar and and check calendar if the event already exists. I don't want duplicate events. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think thats beyond the scope of your original question but:

- For permissions I'd recommend looking at the following: https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

- To avoid duplicates you'd need to query the database before inserting to avoid the creation of a duplicate, a similar question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916243/how-to-avoid-creation-of-duplicate-events-in-calendar-in-android

Comment: Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, event);

FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar

CONTENT_URI is not working for me. A red line appears under it too saying its says in the tool tip message: "Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available." I am assuming the runtime permission for calendar will resolve that issue.

Comment: If I use this... 
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
            eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        } else {
            eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        }

No Fatal Exceptions errors. However, everything adds to the calendar except the reminder stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. Thanks for your help Chris! Much appreciated!